# Derivation of the Frey curve for $a^2+b^6=c^p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

At the bottom of page $5$ in [Bennet Chen's paper](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~ichen/pub/BeCh2.pdf), they give the Frey curve for $a^2+b^6=c^p$ as:

$Y^2=X^3−3(5b^3+ 4ai)bX+ 2(11b^6+ 14ib^3a−2a^2)$

Can anyone tell me how they derived this Frey curve?